# Is there a universally accepted value for a (float) NAN

Tags: java, c++, c

Is a (float) #NAN ("Not A Number") universally assigned the value of 0x7F A0 00 00 or is it different with different compilers?

Comment: No. Depends on the language, compiler, etc, etc. In the future, please do not tag Java, C, and C++ because they are three completely different languages.

Comment: java or c or c++? I don't think it's the same.

Comment: From [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN): *"Two separate kinds of NaNs are provided, termed quiet NaNs and signaling NaNs."*

Comment: It seems like you're talking about the underlying machine representation of NaNs, which is not defined by the languages, but rather by hardware manufacturers and any standards they are following (IEEE FP standards, for instance).

Comment: No. It varies with hardware, language, compiler, etc. There is no standard NAN representation.

Comment: Did anybody mention that it is dependent on language, compiler, hardware, etc. pp.?

Comment: I guess I should have added the circumstances for the question. I once had the bad experience in the Windows C environment where I was polling a liquid flow meter that used a "flow rate" of 0x7F A0 00 00 to signal "air/gas in liquid" problem. That NAN was then passed on to the plant PLC and the PLC suffered a cold start. So, now I am working with Java AND the same flow meters and wondering if the same work around will suffice.

Comment: In that case, why not use `java.lang.Float.isNaN()` so that you do not have to make any guesses and take any chances ?

Answer (score 5):

No.  If there is anything happening in the direction of universally accepting something as far as floats are concerned, then that would be the relevant IEEE standard, but even this standard allows for variations:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: From Mikes link: "For example, a bit-wise IEEE floating-point standard single precision (32-bit) NaN would be: s111 1111 1xxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" So the best work around in detecting a NAN in communications would be to look for the first byte being 0x7F and disregard the other 3 bytes.

Comment: Here is how Java 1.8.0_102 (NetBeans IDE 8.1) sees the world:  <br/>0x7F 00 00 00 returns "The float value is 170141183460469230000000000000000000000.000000".  <br/> 0x7F 80 00 00 returns "The float value is Infinity".   <br/> 0x7F A0 00 00 returns "The float value is NaN"

Comment: @Harvard and Java uses a sub set of IEEE 754 which you might assume more platforms using c and c++ also do. (Not guaranteed but highly likely)

Answer (score 1):

IEEE 754 ("IEEE floating point") defines all representations with maximal exponent value and any non-zero bits in the significand as NANs. Thus, a valid test for single precision would be:

```
uint32_t repr;
memcpy(&repr, &f, sizeof repr);
if ((repr & 0x7fffffff) > 0x7f800000) //...
```

In C, if you don't assume IEEE arithmetic, `2.0+2.0==5.0` is possible, so in practice many of us **do** assume it. It's specified by the optional Annex F to the standard.